# How to multi-hop ssh using connect to server under other locations in Files

Tags: networking, server, ssh, 18.04

I'm new to ubuntu and I am trying to use the functionality of the Files application to add a server to my file locations but it must be accessed through another server.

I was able to connect to server A (blacked out for privacy) using `ssh://user@server.com`
in the Connect to Server section outlined in red below. I would like to connect to server B through server A. Is this possible here or can I only do it via a terminal? It would make copying files over a bit easier.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the following to `~/.ssh/config` on your Ubuntu machine:

```
 Host serverB-proxied
   Hostname serverB  # the real hostname of serverB
   User username     # this is the username on serverB
   ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p user@serverA
```

Then use this as the URL in Files:

```
ssh://serverB-proxied/
```

(It will only work if the sshd on serverA does not have TCP forwarding disabled.)

Answer (score 1):

A way would be to use port forwarding, which would involve some use of terminal. If you create a tunnel via ServerA to ServerB like this:

```
ssh -L 127.0.0.1:222:ServerB:22 user@ServerA
```

Explanation: ssh creates a local port 222 (you may change this to which ever port that is not in use on your local host) - and binds it to 127.0.0.1 only - that forwards all traffic from localhost:222 via ServerA to port 22 on ServerB after you have logged on ServerA.

After that you connect the Files app to ssh://user@localhost:222

This could be set up as a startup script with ssh keys for seamless re-connections.